# After uploading Drupal site from localhost to live hosting, it reports an error

Tags: sql, drupal, content-management-system

After importing the database, changing the "settings.php" file and uploading all the development files to live hosting, loading the site reports the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'u379065817_gk'@'localhost'       
(using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167     
of /home/u379065817/public_html/includes/lock.inc).
```

I used Acquia Dev Desktop while developing the site locally. Tried to find solutions on Drupal community site, but almost every one of it is different. Tried most of them but none worked. :( Thanks in advance for all the effort.

Comment: make sure you have correct host and port as well.

Comment: Try using your hosting IP Address instead of using "local" in setting.php